# After installation, GitLab requires login and password in the web interface

Tags: gitlab

After installation, GitLab requires login and password in the web interface. I didn't install them and I can't do anything about it, I also can't log in to my gitlab, which I have gives an error.

```
Invalid login or password.
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

After the initial installation of gitlab-ce-14, the password is put in a temporary file

/etc/gitlab/initial_ root_ password

This file will be automatically deleted 24 hours after the first execution of reconfigure

Answer (score 0):

try to register using other account and login to gitlab again.
when this step doesn't work try to change your password and then try to login again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installed from official helm chart, then you can get it from here

```
kubectl get secret -n gitlab gitlab-gitlab-initial-root-password -ojsonpath='{.data.password}' | base64 --decode ; echo
```